# Forge: Unable to Open zip file

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

We are using Forge's Design Automation API and we want to send a `.zip` in the WorkItem to the AppBundle.

So our Activity parameter looks like this:

```
  "inputZip": {
              "verb": "get",
              "description": "input file",
              "localName": "test.zip",
              "ondemand": false,
              "required": false,
              "zip": true
            },
```

The Websocket argument is:

```
 "inputZip: { localName: \"test.zip\", url: \"" + url + "\"},
```

This part looks alright, at least we don't have any errors in this part, however, then comes the `AppBundle` code:

```
 string destinationPath = "none";

        string extractPath = Path.GetFullPath(currentDir);
        if (!extractPath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            extractPath += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        }

        using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(@".\test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".rfa", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    entry.ExtractToFile("testExtractedFile");

                    // Gets the full path to ensure that relative segments are removed.
                    destinationPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
                    if (destinationPath.StartsWith(extractPath, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        entry.ExtractToFile(destinationPath);
                    }


                    Console.WriteLine(" * - * File name = " + entry.FullName);
                    Console.WriteLine(" * - * File extracted from zip file succesfully! * - * ");
                    //entry.Open();
                }
            }
        }
        var familyFullPath = destinationPath;
```

The problem is that we are unable to open the zip file, we get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'T:\Aces\Jobs\...\test.zip' is denied.
```

The error happens at line `using (ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.Open(@".\test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read))`. Any idea how to bypass this?

The idea is to extract 2 files which are located in this one particular zip file in the AppBundle, and then open one of them with `document.LoadFamily(familyFullPath, out Family family)` (one of the files is a family file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip is uncompressed to the folder specified in localname.
Please refer to: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-POST/#body-structure -> arguments -> * -> XrefTreeArgument -> pathInZip

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this part "Any path reference to this argument will expand to full path of localName.", what does this mean exaclty? Does that mean that I can't access it at @".\test.zip" but rather at it's whole path or? If yes, how do I know it's whole path?

Comment: Ok, got it, I understand now.. thanks!